# c# не получается получить данные из класса

Tags: c#, классы

У меня есть класс Auth, в который записываются данные пользователя, который только что вошёл в систему.

```
    public class Auth
    {
        private string login = null;
        private string pass = null;
        private bool isOkay = false;

        public string Login
        {
            get { return this.login; }
            set { this.login = value; }
        }
        public string Pass
        {
            get { return this.pass; }
            set { this.pass = value; }
        }
        public bool IsOkay
        {
            get { return this.isOkay; }
            set { this.isOkay = value; }
        }
    }
```

В основном методе Form1 есть таймер, который проверяет каждую секунду, вошёл ли пользователь в систему:

```
    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Auth auth = new Auth(); //создание экземпляра класса Auth
        if (auth.IsOkay == true)
        {
            panelSideMenu.Enabled = true; //панель, которая разблокируется только в случае, если пользователь авторизовался
            timer1.Stop();
        }
        else
            panelSideMenu.Enabled = false;
    }
```

p.s. после успешной авторизации в 3 методе выполняется этот код (то есть, "присваиваем пользователя в переменные класса"):

```
    Auth auth = new Auth();
    auth.Login = log;
    auth.Pass = pass;
    auth.IsOkay = true;
```

Вроде, давно занимаюсь программированием, но такая глупая ошибка вогнала в тупик....

Comment: `new Auth();` - что это? Наверно "создать новый", верно? Так может нужна ссылка?

Comment: https://i2.paste.pics/DE6DB.png - Вы имеете ввиду, что нужно сделать так?

Comment: Вы ведь "давно программируете") Представьте, что у вас есть корзинка с яблоками, вы хотите оттуда взять их кол-во. Ваши действия? Вот сейчас вы выкидываете старую корзинку с нужными вам данными и создаете новую, пустую. Вы в одном методе (как я понял) пишете `Auth auth = new Auth();`, создавая локальную переменную с нужными данными, а потом в тике таймера опять пишете `Auth auth = new Auth();`, создавая опять новую, локальную переменную. В C# классы - ссылочный тип, создайте его за пределами метода, один раз инициализируйте и дальше используйте внутренние данные где хотите.

Comment: " public static Authentication auth = new Authentication(); " - сделать что-то такое в любом методе (например в Form1) и везде обращаться к нему? (Form1.auth......) (p.s. до этого я писал мелкие программы, в которых обходился без наследования и прочего, а сейчас вот припёрло и нужно как-то начинать это дело писать)

Comment: Ну для начала так, да. Один объект на всю вашу логику.

Comment: Допустим, я не читал ничьи больше комментарии. Я трижды перечитал вопрос, но не нашел в вопросе вопроса. Я даже не нашел ни одного вопросительного знака. На что нужно отвечать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Authentication auth = new Authentication();
```

Необходимо написать это в любом методе и обращаться уже данному инициализированному экземпляру (вдруг кому-то поможет в будущем)